# How to split time column into intervals (say 30 min or 1 h) and plot it against Date or Month

Tags: r, time, ggplot2, intervals

I am trying to plot time by intervals say 15 min, 30 min or 1 hour on x-axis but I am not getting the right plot.

My data frame is `transform_time` and it has 1000+ records. I have used:

```
ggplot(transform_time, aes(x = transform_time$TIME_START, y=transform_time$TIME_END, col=EVENT_TYPE)) +
   geom_line(size = 1) + 
   scale_x_datetime(limits = c(as.POSIXct("2014-05-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-05-31 23:59:59"))) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:31, limits=c(0,31))

ggplot(Bad_Node, aes(x=transform_time$TIME_START, y=transform_time$OAR_INCIDENT_ID)) +
   geom_point()

EVENT_TYPE      DATE           TIME_START    TIME_END
event A         9/18/2014      14:47:01      16:53:07
event B         9/18/2014      15:52:16      17:08:30
event A         9/18/2014      16:26:19      16:53:58
event C         9/20/2014      19:25:51      19:25:51
event B         9/23/2014       3:40:39       4:38:07
event D         9/25/2014       8:15:40       8:59:40
```

I want to plot time with the above mentioned intervals on X-axis.

Comment: You don't need the `transform_time$` part inside the `aes` when your data is set to `transform_time`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use two different scales on the same axis (like `scale_x_datetime() + scale_x_continuous()`). Moreover, if you want the scale to work as expected, you should make sure the data are in the right format. Transforme TIME_START and TIME_END so they are actually recognized as dates :

```
## data sample
transform_time <- read.table(text="
EVENT_TYPE      DATE           TIME_START    TIME_END
eventA         9/18/2014      14:47:01      16:53:07
eventB         9/18/2014      15:52:16      17:08:30
eventA         9/18/2014      16:26:19      16:53:58
eventC         9/20/2014      19:25:51      19:25:51
eventB         9/23/2014       3:40:39       4:38:07
eventD         9/25/2014       8:15:40       8:59:40",head=TRUE)

## Format variables
transform_time$TIME_START <- as.POSIXct(transform_time$TIME_START,format="%T")
transform_time$TIME_END <- as.POSIXct(transform_time$TIME_END,format="%T")
```

You can then use `scale_x_datetime`. Note that in this example, I use geom_point rather than geom_line because you only give one data point for each group.

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(transform_time, aes(x = TIME_START, y=TIME_END, col=EVENT_TYPE)) +
  geom_point(size = 10) + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks="30 min",minor_breaks = "15 min",labels=date_format("%H:%M")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

as @Jaap said in the comment, first make sure you should not repeat the dataframe's name inside `aes`.

Comment: thank you @scoa & Jaap. This one worked for me. In one of my other assignment, I am doing the same thing, making time intervals, but not able to make those. I am using the following

pointA <- ggplot(fnode, aes(x=TIME, y=Temperature, group=as.factor(ISFAILED), color=as.factor(ISFAILED))) 
 + geom_line() 
 + geom_point(aes(x=fnode$TIME, y=fnode$Temperature, group=as.factor(ISFAILED), color=as.factor(ISFAILED), fill=as.factor(ISFAILED)), size=4) 
 + scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(0:24)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0:60)).

I want to show hours on the X-Axis. Can you please help me with also.

Comment: you need `scale_x_datetime(breaks="1 hour")`

Comment: I tried with scale_x_datetime(breaks="1 hour") @scoa... but its throwing me an error ... "Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only " 


> class(fnode$TIME)
[1] "character"

Comment: `point_temp$TIME <- as.POSIXct(point_temp$TIME,format="%d %T")` You may have to play with the format, see `?strptime` if this one doesn't work

Comment: After I use 
point_temp$TIME <- as.POSIXct(point_temp$TIME,format="%d %T") ... The column is becoming "NA". Also when I am using "strptime" then also the column displays "NA"

Comment: typing `?strptime` will bring up the help of function `striptime`, where the various date format are explained. You should find one that suits your data. The process is exactly the same as the one I explain in my answer

Comment: else `point_temp$TIME <- as.POSIXct(do.call(rbind,strsplit(as.character(point_temp$TIME)," "))[,2],format="%H:%M")`

Comment: fnode$TIME <- strptime(as.POSIXct(augfnode$TIME),format="%d %T")

fnode$minute <- strptime(augfnode$minute, "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%OS")

I did make use of the above two , but with no Success. Please help. I am only stuck with this problem. I will be completing with my assignment once I am done with this problem @scoa

Comment: When I am using the above code 

point_temp$TIME <- as.POSIXct(do.call(rbind,strsplit(as.character(point_temp$TIME)," "))[,2],format="%H:%M")

which you have provided @scoa , it is again throwing me an error .... " Error in do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(augfnode$minute), " "))[,  : 
  subscript out of bounds "

Answer (score 0):

My data frame for the above mentioned problem in comment is as follows

data set is (point_temp)

`LOCATION      TIME         ISFAILED     Temperature`

`Point1      8/5/2014 5:42   0       51
Point1      8/5/2014 5:44   0       51
Point1      8/5/2014 5:47   0       51
Point1      8/5/2014 5:52   0       51
Point1      8/5/2014 5:57   0       51
Point1      8/5/2014 6:01   1       44
Point1      8/5/2014 6:02   0       44
Point1      8/5/2014 6:07   0       44
Point1      8/5/2014 6:12   0       44
Point1      8/5/2014 6:17   0       27
Point1      8/5/2014 6:17   0       27
Point1      8/5/2014 6:23   0       27`